# Why is accuracy higher with Caffe than with tf.keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, caffe

I converted a model from tf.keras to caffe. When I evaluate the model with Caffe on the test set, I find that the accuracy is higher with caffe than with tf.keras. I can't think of a way to get a hand on the source of the problem (if there's a problem in the first place...) 
 
Is this difference due to the lower-level libraries used for accelerating the computations (I am thinking of cudnn and the caffe engine)? Is there a well-known accuracy problem with the keras module of tensorflow?
 
By the way, there are other people that have a similar issue:

> https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4444

Answer (score 1):

This can happen.

Once you convert your keras .h5 model to .caffemodel, the weights are numerically copied. But, internally you'll load your model to Caffe and not Keras.

As, caffe and keras are two different libraries, their internal algorithms can vary slightly. Also if you change your pre-processing scheme that can change the result too. Usually, if you use pruning (to optimize the size) the performance can go low, in the weird case this can be thought of as an extreme regularization and act as a performance booster in test.

Comment: When you say algorithms do you mean the engine? But caffe and tf both use cuda and cudnn, so where's the difference between their algorithms? And what do you mean by pruning?

Comment: are you using same version of cudnn? Also, did you train and ran inference with same cudnn version for both tensorflow, caffe? 
pruning is a technique when you remove some parameters to reduce number of size of model, while keeping similar performance.